# Get a cumulative sum for each month in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, count, distinct

Hi I have a table with 3 columns.

```
custid  p_date          vegetable
0000009 07-APR-20       tomato
0000013 25-MAR-20       potato
0000015 11-APR-19       tomato
0000016 23-JUL-18       potato
0000019 19-JUL-18       potato
0000018 07-JUN-20       turnip
0000020 12-JUL-18       turnip
0000022 23-JUL-18       potato
0000023 12-JUL-18       turnip
0000024 11-AUG-20       potato
```

I need to calculate the distinct count for the customers based on the veggie
column along with cumulative sum for each month

the output should have below columns

```
date        
tomato_ct 
cum_tomato_ct
potato_ct
cum_potato_ct
turnip_ct        
cum_turnip_ct
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you want, not just the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want monthly counts and cumulative counts pivoted by vegetable, you can do:

```
select trunc(p_date, 'month') as p_month,
    sum(case when vegetable = 'tomato' then 1 else 0 end) as tomato_ct,
    sum(sum(case when vegetable = 'tomato' then 1 else 0 end)) over(order by trunc(p_date, 'month')) as cum_tomato_ct,
    sum(case when vegetable = 'potato' then 1 else 0 end) as potato_ct,
    sum(sum(case when vegetable = 'potato' then 1 else 0 end)) over(order by trunc(p_date, 'month')) as cum_potato_ct,
    sum(case when vegetable = 'turnip' then 1 else 0 end) as turnip_ct,
    sum(sum(case when vegetable = 'turnip' then 1 else 0 end)) over(order by trunc(p_date, 'month')) as cum_turnip_ct
from mytable
group by trunc(p_date, 'month')
```

You mentioned that you want a count of *distinct* customers. If you want to count each customer only once par vegetable, on their earliest appearance, then I would recommend two levels of aggregation:

```
select trunc(p_date, 'month') as p_month,
    sum(case when vegetable = 'tomato' then 1 else 0 end) as tomato_ct,
    sum(sum(case when vegetable = 'tomato' then 1 else 0 end)) over(order by trunc(p_date, 'month')) as cum_tomato_ct,
    sum(case when vegetable = 'potato' then 1 else 0 end) as potato_ct,
    sum(sum(case when vegetable = 'potato' then 1 else 0 end)) over(order by trunc(p_date, 'month')) as cum_potato_ct,
    sum(case when vegetable = 'turnip' then 1 else 0 end) as turnip_ct,
    sum(sum(case when vegetable = 'turnip' then 1 else 0 end)) over(order by trunc(p_date, 'month')) as cum_turnip_ct
from (
    select cust_id, vegetable, min(p_date) as p_date
    from mytable
    group by cust_id, vegetable
) t
group by trunc(p_date, 'month')
```

Comment: I got my desired output. Thank you. Validating the count

Comment: I disagree!!! This will throw an error as analytical functions are not allowed in the aggregate function.

Comment: @Popeye: that's the other way around here: the aggregate function is inside the analytic function.

Comment: In the same query, if i need total cust count and cumulative count, how shd i edit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of `analytical` function and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SQL>
SQL> -- sample data
SQL> WITH YOUR_TABLE(custid,  p_date,          vegetable) AS
  2  (SELECT '0000009', TO_DATE('07-APR-20','DD-MON-RR'),       'tomato' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '0000013', TO_DATE('25-MAR-20','DD-MON-RR'),       'potato' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT '0000015', TO_DATE('11-APR-19','DD-MON-RR'),       'tomato' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT '0000016', TO_DATE('23-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'),       'potato' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT '0000019', TO_DATE('19-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'),       'potato' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT '0000018', TO_DATE('07-JUN-20','DD-MON-RR'),       'turnip' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT '0000020', TO_DATE('12-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'),       'turnip' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  9  SELECT '0000022', TO_DATE('23-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'),       'potato' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 10  SELECT '0000023', TO_DATE('12-JUL-18','DD-MON-RR'),       'turnip' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 11  SELECT '0000024', TO_DATE('11-AUG-20','DD-MON-RR'),       'potato' FROM DUAL)
 12  -- actual query starts from here
 13  SELECT P_DATE,
 14     COUNT(CASE WHEN vegetable = 'tomato' THEN 1 END) AS TOMATO_CT,
 15     MAX(TOMATO_CNT) AS CUM_TOMATO_CT,
 16     COUNT(CASE WHEN vegetable = 'potato' THEN 1 END) AS POTATO_CT,
 17     MAX(POTATO_CNT) AS CUM_POTATO_CT,
 18     COUNT(CASE WHEN vegetable = 'turnip' THEN 1 END) AS TURNIP_CT,
 19     MAX(TURNIP_CNT) AS CUM_TURNIP_CT
 20    FROM
 21    (SELECT T.*,
 22   COUNT(CASE WHEN vegetable = 'tomato' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY P_DATE) AS TOMATO_CNT,
 23   COUNT(CASE WHEN vegetable = 'potato' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY P_DATE) AS POTATO_CNT,
 24   COUNT(CASE WHEN vegetable = 'turnip' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY P_DATE) AS TURNIP_CNT
 25  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT custid, TRUNC(p_date,'MON') P_DATE, vegetable FROM YOUR_TABLE) T
 26     )
 27   GROUP BY P_DATE
 28   ORDER BY P_DATE;

P_DATE                TOMATO_CT CUM_TOMATO_CT  POTATO_CT CUM_POTATO_CT  TURNIP_CT CUM_TURNIP_CT
-------------------- ---------- ------------- ---------- ------------- ---------- -------------
01-JUL-2018 00:00:00          0             0          3             3          2             2
01-APR-2019 00:00:00          1             1          0             3          0             2
01-MAR-2020 00:00:00          0             1          1             4          0             2
01-APR-2020 00:00:00          1             2          0             4          0             2
01-JUN-2020 00:00:00          0             2          0             4          1             3
01-AUG-2020 00:00:00          0             2          1             5          0             3

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Can you pls explain the above query. How max(tomato_cnt) gives the cumulative sum?

Comment: Because the inner query has the cumulative calculation for all mentioned veggies. and by using MAX, It is using the max of all cumulative count for the grouped month. If you will execute the inner query alone then you will be able to see the logic behind the MAX in outer query